# make same action to each value of array vuejs

Tags: javascript, arrays, vuejs2

I'm making many file inputs (array) but have same initial word like this :

```
<input type file="file0"/>
<input type file="file1"/>
```

I want all of them have same action

```
this.$upload.reset('fileX', {
 url: 'documentations/upload'
});
```

I have tried

`this.$upload.reset('file*'`
`this.$upload.reset('file{*}'`
`this.$upload.reset('file${*}'`

Answer (score 0):

If you are uploading files using vue.js, why not you listen onChange event:

```
<input type="file" v-on:change="onFileChange" name="file0">
<input type="file" v-on:change="onFileChange" name="file1">
```

Then declare the common method in `methods` of vue declaration:

```
methods: {
    onFileChange(e) {
      var files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;
      if (files.length){
            // Perform common action
      }
 }
```